# Get value corresponding to column value in Multi array in C#

Tags: c#

Hello I have an **Multi Array**. I want to retrieve value of 2nd column based on first column. I have an **post count** property, based on that i want to check if that post count is >= first column value and accordingly assign the second column value.

I have tried this to check if its >= as follows :

```
if(postcount >= groupArray[2,0])
{
groupid = [2,1]
}
```

But i have to write this for all left column values... i.e. 3 times

This is my Array :

```
int[,] groupArray = new int[3,2]
                {
                  {0,4},
                  {50,5},
                  {100,6}
};
```

According to the above array, if my post count reaches 50.. my groupid should be 5. So is there a better way to optimize the code i've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following function:

```
int GetGroupId(int[,] values, int postCount)
{
    var groupId = -1;
    for(var i = 0; i < values.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
        if(postCount >= values[i, 0])
            groupId = values[i, 1];

    return groupId;
}
```

Usage:

```
var arr = new int[3, 2]
{
    {0, 4},
    {50, 5},
    {100, 6}
};

var a = GetGroupId(arr, 20); // 4
var b = GetGroupId(arr, 60); // 5
```

However, I would suggest using an array of objects or tuples instead of a 2D array to make it more readable and maintainable. Having field names like `MinPostCount` and `GroupId` is much better than cryptic magic number indices.